# If I worked out a problem I coudn't find answered directly, how do I post my solution?

Tags: discussion, answers, asking-questions

I had a MySQL problem I was trying to solve, had a hard time figuring out how to frame a question, got close, but never asked a question and I never did find my exact situation addressed. After a bunch of searching, I figured out the answer by patching together parts of other answers and researching elements that turned out to be part of the solution. I think it's a good solution, and both the solution and suggestions about how to frame the question might be useful to users. So how do I post that?

Comment: You could ask on the site's site specific meta about how to frame the question, posting whatever attempts you have and what you've found.  The site's chat would also be an okay place for something like that.

Comment: Before opening a new question I would edit your existing question, and resolve the fact, you never asked a question in the question body.  “but never asked a question and I never did find my exact situation addressed.“ to be clear the reason your question was closed was because you never asked a question.  Appears the question was deleted.  I suggest just opening a new question but making sure you actually ask a question even if you now know the answer to your problem.

Comment: Kinda related from SF; https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/9184/posting-question-and-answer-for-information-purposes

Answer (score 5):

If you have what you think is a unique problem and you've already solved it, you can actually ask and answer a question simultaneously.

Generally, what I recommend is writing the question as if you don't know the answer at all. Phrase it precisely and explain it in such a way that it's clear and obvious that the existing questions and their solutions are different.

Then, before submitting the question, click the tick box next to the text that reads

> Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style

Here, post your solution. Explain how you found it, link to the other answers that you used to solve your problem and explain it as if you're answering someone else's question.

Submit them both. You may still get other answers - perhaps your solution isn't the perfect one or other people figured it out in a different way. That's OK. You may also get some commentary on your solution and whether it's a good one or not.

It's important, however, that you explain the question thoroughly enough that other people *can* write answers. Don't write half a question because you already know the answer. In fact, because you already know the answer, you should probably be *better* able to write a useful question.

Some users aren't big fans of these types of question/answer posts but they are definitely allowed and part of the way the site works.